# Python Session Update Cookie Value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, session-cookies

In python session how can I update the value for one cookie?

for example I want to add a to its right.

```
cookie_obj = requests.cookies.create_cookie(name="name", value="the cookie works")
s.cookies.set_cookie(cookie_obj)
```

This Adds new cookie but I want to update current one's value only.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple, cookies can be accessed as dictionary values, and that would look something like this

```
s.cookies['cookie_name'] = '25'
s.cookies['cookie2'] = '25'
```

Here is a little [demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25501603/9231525):

```
>>> import requests
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/cookies'
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> s.headers.update({
...     'Origin':urlparse(url).netloc,
...     'Referer':url
... })
>>> r = s.get(url)
>>> s.cookies['cookie1'] = '25'
>>> s.cookies['cookie2'] = '25'
>>> r = s.get(url, headers={'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'})
>>> print(r.text)
{"cookies": {"cookie1": "25", "cookie2": "25"}}
```